# How to get products in JSON format from OpenCart using phonegap/jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, opencart

Is there anyway, to fetch product catalog in JSON format from my OpenCart store, from a phonegap mobile application using Ajax, JavaScript/jQuery. Does OpenCart allow for such a thing?

Any ideas or code are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OcJoy is going right way but the solution provided will contain all the page data which I guess is not Your desired output.

Instead of his solution, You should do something like this (assuming You need only the products JSON array) before `$this->response->setOutput($this->render());`:

```
if(isset($this->request->get['json'])) {
    echo json_encode($this->data['products']);
    die;
} else
```

Then after hitting `http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&json` only the JSON of products array of category with ID 20 will be output.

---

**EDIT:** to call this from within a template as an AJAX request, You could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/category&path=<CATEGORY_ID>&json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        complete: function() {
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                // do something here with the products in data array
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure to replace `<CATEGORY_ID>` with the right value in the URL above and to add the desired functionality within the `success` callback function.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the example, if it is possible would you mind giving me an example, how to consume this with .ajax. I have done this before but only consuming jsonp, and I know jQuery adds a ?callback after my url. How can I get the data from this ?

Comment: @DaimanLoks What do You mean by calling this from AJAX? Like from which template (page)? OpenCart is full of AJAX calls, You could get an example from e.g. `catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/register.tpl` or `.../template/product/product.tpl` - there should be a couple of `jQuery.load()` or `jQuery.post()` calls... If You'd encounter problems finding an appropriate example, let me know.

Comment: Sorry I mean, calling it using the jQuery .ajax method. As you can see I am not very savy when it comes to this technologies.

Comment: I am getting this error, when trying to get the data. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` I am using actually a module called `opencart-webap` that allows you to fetch data as a RESTapi.

Comment: @DaimanLoks Aren't You trying to load the products from `http://domain1.com/` into another installation at `http://otherdomain.com/`??? I guess this goes behind the scope of this question and should be asked as a new problem regarding the module and full problem description... Huh?

Comment: I am trying to fetch this data from a phonegap mobile application. As it is mentioned on my question title :)

Comment: And what is wrong with hitting the URL with `&json` parameter directly? I doubt this phonegap application will let You to do a **cross-domain** AJAX request as it is normally forbidden from everywhere (and in every browser) as a security protection.

Answer (score 1):

In catalog/controller/product/catalog.php  before

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

paste this code

```
if (isset( $this->request->get['json'])) $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($this->data));  else
```

and go  link http://opencart.examle/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&json

Comment: I specifically checked the code again on different versions 1.5.x . If you replace `$this->response->setOutput($this->render()); ` to this  `if(isset( $this->request->get['json'])) $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($this->data));  else    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());`

Comment: You can get the full json response, including breadcrumbs,pagination,language,products and category info by my solution

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the response, I thought it would be rendered as an HTML but with json encoded data. Anyway, OP requested a solution for just the products array not whole page with useless breadcrumbs, categories, category description, sorting and paging options, etc...