# (Opencart) How to reload a view of another controller which uses ajax to render response to this view?

Tags: opencart-3

The core Product/Category controller uses setOutput to render back the result of a view (that lacks $.ajax) to some view (which seemingly has $.ajax inside). I need to be able to refresh the product list from a custom controller. How can I do it?

I tried adding a function inside the Product/Category controller and setting up ajax communication with it, but that doesn't work (I think that it could be the way, I just don't know what to do here). I can only get a response from this ocmod function to the custom module's twig where my $.ajax request originates, but **I need to be able to change the view of the Product/Catalog controller** (the product list).

The custom function (inside core Product/Catalog controller) is as follows:

```php
public function start_refresh() {

        if ($this->request->post['refresh_needed']) {

            $data = array();
            $data['test_data'] = $this->request->post['test_data'];
            $this->response->setOutput(
                $this->load->view('product/category_session', $data)
            );

        };

    }
```

**EDIT**: In the above custom function which is inside the core Product/Category, I tried creating the loading of the Product/Category controller as shown below, but I am getting a **404 error**, even though in the console the **category.php file has has the right html rendering** with "This category is empty of products."

```php
$data = array();         
$this->load->controller('product/category', $data);
$this->response->setOutput(
     $this->load->view('product/category', $data)
);            
return $this->response->getOutput();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to it the following way after reading the answer from [How to get products in JSON format from OpenCart using phonegap/jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919807/how-to-get-products-in-json-format-from-opencart-using-phonegap-jquerymobile).

From the ajax I called the products/category directly and not my custom function inside of the product/category controller as in the question, and when I got reponse back containing the html output of the view, I reloaded a div I made in the product/category.twig with that html using jQuery. The ajax was

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/category&path=18&json',
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        complete: function() {
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');     
            if (data.length > 0) {
                console.log(data); 
                $('#mydiv').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

and the code I added to product/category.php was

```php
    if(isset($this->request->get['json'])) {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/view_for_mydiv', $data));
    } else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));           
    }
```

As you may notice I added a div inside product/category.twig called mydiv, which I placed exactly where I wanted the html to go and then I created a twig called view_for_mydiv.twig inside default/product/category/ folder, the html of which the product/category controller would send back instead of its general twig when it saw that an ajax call had been made to it. The #mydiv div located inside category.twig wraps the html that is the same html that gets produced when view_for_mydiv.twig is used to render product/category.