# (Opencart) How to load a controller in a function and not break ajax with that function?

Tags: opencart

Is there a way to load controller (product/category) within some contained space, so that the ajax to the custom function within that controller doesn't break?

I'm basically loading (from ajax) a custom function which is inside a core contoller product/category. In this function I need to reload the the product/category controller to get new product list based on ajax data I sent to the function, to then return it as a response to the original ajax.

When I try to do

```php
$this->load->controller('product/category')
```

it beaks the ajax I set up with the function and in the console I see 404.

I tried using

```php
$foo = $this->load->controller('product/category')
```

and it works, but I need to also execute

```php
$this->load->view('product/category')
```

and I don't know how to do it without breaking ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I did what I essentially wanted (see the middle of my question, namely the part about the ultimate need to refresh my product list using ajax) the other way (after reading up [How to get products in JSON format from OpenCart using phonegap/jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919807/how-to-get-products-in-json-format-from-opencart-using-phonegap-jquerymobile)): from the ajax I called the products/category directly and not my custom function inside of the product/category controller as in the question, and when I got reponse back containing the html output of the view, I reloaded a div I made in the product/category.twig with that html using jQuery. The ajax was

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/category&path=18&json',
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        complete: function() {
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');     
            if (data.length > 0) {
                console.log(data); 
                $('#mydiv').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

and the code I added to product/category.php was

```php
    if(isset($this->request->get['json'])) {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/view_for_mydiv', $data));
    } else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));           
    }
```

As you may notice I added a div inside product/category.twig called mydiv, which I placed exactly where I wanted the html to go and then I created a twig called view_for_mydiv.twig inside default/product/category/ folder, the html of which the product/category controller would send back instead of its general twig when it saw that an ajax call had been made to it. The #mydiv div located inside category.twig wraps the html that is the same html that gets produced when view_for_mydiv.twig is used to render product/category.